# MySQL register doesnt work

Tags: mysql

Okay, here are my two codes: register.php and finish.php

register.php:

```
<?php include("yla.php"); ?>

<form action="finish.php" method="POST">
Etunimi: <input type="text" name="etunimi" /></br>
Sukunimi: <input type="text" name="sukunimi" /></br>
Henkilötunnus: <input type="text" name="henktun" /></br>
Osoite: <input type="text" name="osoite" /></br>
Postinumero: <input type="text" name="postiosoite" /></br>
Käyttäjänimi: <input type="text" name="kayttajanimi" /></br>
Salasana: <input type="password" name="salasana" /></br>
Kirjoita salasana uudelleen: <input type="password" name="re-password" /></br>
<input type="submit" value="Lähetä" />
</form>
<?php include("ala.php"); ?>
```

and finish.php

```
<?php

//STEP 1 Connect To Database

$connect = mysqli_connect("HOST", "USERNAME", "PWD", "DB")
{
die("MySQL could not connect!");
}

/*
$DB = mysqli_select_db('DB');

if(!$DB)
{
die("My SQL could not select Database!");
}
*/

//STEP 2 Declare Variables

$Etunimi = $_POST['etunimi'];
$Sukunimi = $_POST['sukunimi'];
$Henkilotunnus = $_POST['henktun'];
$Osoite = $_POST['osoite'];
$Postinumero = $_POST['postinumero'];
$Kayttajanimi = $_POST['kayttajanimi'];
$salasana = $_POST['salasana'];
$Re_Password = $_POST['re-password'];

//STEP 3 Check To See If All Information Is Correct

if($Kayttajanimi == "")
{
die("Et antanut käyttäjänimeä");
}

if($salasana == "" || $Re_Password == "")
{
die("et antanut yhtä salasanoistasi");
}



if($salasana != $Re_Password)
{
die("Salasanat ei täsmää");
}



//STEP 4 Insert Information Into MySQL Database

if(!mysqli_query("INSERT INTO Asiakas (Etunimi, Sukunimi, Henkilotunnus, Osoite, Postinumero, Kayttajanimi, salasana)
VALUES ('$Etunimi', '$Sukunimi', '$Henkilotunnus', '$Osoite', '$Postinumero', '$Kayttajanimi', '$salasana')"))
{
*die("We could not register you due to a mysql error (Contact the website owner if this continues to happen.)");            <--- HERE IS WHERE THE ERROR HAPPENS*
}**

?>
```

*die("We could not register you due to a mysql error (Contact the website owner if this continues to happen.)");            <--- HERE IS WHERE THE ERROR HAPPENS*

This is the error and I dont know what's wrong and i've been trying to figure this out for hours, so can somebody please help me?

Comment: have you confirmed your sql insert works from some other tool?

Comment: try to print mysql_error() instead customer error message.

Comment: I'd also study something about SQL Injection because this is the exact way of how to NOT do it!

Comment: Also, use propper error handling. die() is not the way to go about.

Comment: I hope that is not your real password.  If it is you, might want to change it **RIGHT NOW.**

Comment: You should verify if you have some wrong data types you're trying to store

Comment: So what should I replace the die with? And that isn't the real password, it's our old password so no worries about that.

Comment: instead of the `die("we could...")`, write `print "Error found: ". mysql_error();` Show us what that line's output is. That clarifies your error

Comment: It doesnt seem to work, it just posts "Error found" and blank, did I do something wrong here?

Comment: Sorry, I believe with mysqli it's got to be: `mysqli_error($connect)`

Comment: print "Error found: ". mysqli_error($connect); <- This way? And I'm sorry I'm bad at MySQL so sorry for the noobish questions. It just doesnt seem to work, just prints out "Error found" and blank still. And I have the underscore too

Comment: Yes like that. Mind the underscore between mysqli and error! Edit your post and add the output of that. That will tell you what the error exactly is.

Comment: It just doesnt seem  to work, still prints out Error found and a blank, I have the underscore yeah

Comment: also change: `mysqli_query("SELECT...")` to `mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT ...")`

Comment: YES! It started working, you just saved my day, thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

To make summary:

```
<?php

//STEP 1 Connect To Database


if($connect = mysqli_connect("HOST", "USERNAME", "PWD", "DB")) {
echo "MySQL could not connect!";
}
else {
/*
$DB = mysqli_select_db('DB');

if(!$DB)
{
die("My SQL could not select Database!");
}
*/

//STEP 2 Declare Variables

$Etunimi        = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['etunimi']);
$Sukunimi       = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['sukunimi']);
$Henkilotunnus  = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['henktun']);
$Osoite         = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['osoite']);
$Postinumero    = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['postinumero']);
$Kayttajanimi   = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['kayttajanimi']);
$salasana       = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['salasana']);
$Re_Password    = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['re-password']);

//STEP 3 Check To See If All Information Is Correct

if($Kayttajanimi == "")
{
    echo "Et antanut käyttäjänimeä";
}
elseif($salasana == "" || $Re_Password == "")
{
    echo "et antanut yhtä salasanoistasi";
}
elseif($salasana != $Re_Password)
{
    echo "Salasanat ei täsmää";
}
else {
    //STEP 4 Insert Information Into MySQL Database
    $sql = "INSERT INTO 
                Asiakas 
                (Etunimi, Sukunimi, Henkilotunnus, Osoite, Postinumero, Kayttajanimi, salasana)
            VALUES 
                ('".$Etunimi."', '".$Sukunimi."', '".$Henkilotunnus."', '".$Osoite."', '".$Postinumero."', '".$Kayttajanimi."', '".$salasana."')";

    if(!mysqli_query($connect, $sql))
    {
        echo "An error occurred: ". mysqli_error($connect);
    }
}
}
?>
```